# permission denied for rename function in C on windows

Tags: c, windows

I have an application developed in C. This application is supported across multiple platforms. There is one functionality where we are transferring files via file transfer protocol to different machine or to any other directory on local machine. I want to include a functionality where I can transfer the file with some temporary name and once the transfer is complete, I want to rename the file with the correct name (the actual file name).

I tried using simple rename() function. It works fine in Unix and Linux machines. But it does not work on Windows. It is giving me an error code of 13(Permission denied error).

First thing, I checked in msdn to know the functionality of rename if I have to grant some permissions to the file etc.

1. I granted full permissions to the file (lets say it is 777).
2. I read in few other posts that I should close the file descriptor before renaming the file. I did that too. It still gives the same error.
3. Few other posts mentioned about the owner of the file and that of the application. The application will run as a SYSTEM user. (But this should not affect the behavior, because I tried the same rename function in my application as follows:

This works fine from my application:

```
rename("C:/abc/aaa.txt","C:/abc/zzz.txt");
```

but

```
rename(My_path,"C:/abc/zzz.txt");
```

doesn't work, where `My_path` when printed displays `C:/abc/test.txt`.

How can I rename a file? I need it to work on multiple platforms. 
Are there any other things I should be trying to make it work.?

Comment: We need a complete, self-contained test program that reproduces the problem.  Ideally this program would create all of the files and directories needed to demonstrate the problem itself, but a .bat file would also do, if that's easier.

Comment: I am trying to add this part of the code in one of the files of a copyright s/w application. It is extremely huge and has to be linked to thousands of libraries. So sharing of any executables or libraries will not be possible.

Comment: Snippet would be : 
fun1(datatype1, datatype2)
{
//get the data for that device protocol
if(path is not null)  /* path refers to the location where the file which needs to be renamed is present */
{
   // Want to add rename before it is deallocated
   deallocate(path);
}
}

Comment: Shouldn't you use backslashes on Windows?

Comment: Works fine with backslashs and also forward slashes. Its one and the same.

Comment: We don't wanna see something huge and proprietary.  We want a *simple, self-contained test program* that triggers the same problem.  Write it from scratch.  You should be able to reproduce this problem in less than 50 lines of code.  It's quite likely that you will discover what is wrong in the process of writing the test program, and even if you don't, we are much more likely to be able to help once we see it.

Comment: @dbrank0 All the C-level Win32 APIs accept both \ and / as path separators.  CMD.EXE is pickier, but you can get away with forward slashes a lot of the time.  I don't know about PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, but the issue was slightly different.  If I did the following sequence of function calls, I got "Permission Denied" when calling the rename function.

```
fopen
fwrite
rename
fclose
```

The solution was to close the file first, before doing the rename.

```
fopen
fwrite
fclose
rename
```

Comment: This also resolved my problem but I was not getting 'permission denied.' instead, errno was 13 : data is invalid.

Comment: Addendum to my previous comment: it appears that on Ubuntu at least, 13 is indeed 'Permission denied', but I used FormatMessage on Windows, which is apparently not capable of handling `errno`. Looks like you need to use `strerror_s` to get the correct message from errno on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
rename("C:/abc/aaa.txt","C:/abc/zzz.txt");
```

works but

```
rename(My_path,"C:/abc/zzz.txt");
```

does not, in the exact same spot in the program (i.e. replacing one line with another and making no changes), then there might be something wrong with the variable My_path. What is the type of this variable? If it is a char array (since this is C), is it terminated appropriately? And is it exactly equal to "C:/abc/aaa.txt"?

(I wish I could post this as a comment/clarification rather than as an answer but my rep isn't good enough :( )

Comment: I am assuming that the variable is appropriate. It is a permission issue. Need to grant appropriate permissions from the application so that rename is successful.
Why I am assuming that the var is proper is because:
I tried giving something like this:
char *str = "C:/abc/test.txt";
rename(str,"C:/abc/zzz.txt"); //works fine
/* My_var and str are same */